# No access to index file

Tags: git, indexing

I cannot acces my git index file. I can start gitk, check my branches and my remotes, but the command `git status` leads to the error message `fatal: index file open failed: input/output error`. When I check the contents of my .git directory with `ls -l` (I work with the bash and Ubuntu GNU/Linux) the line describing the index file is `-????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? index`. Clearly, there's something wrong with my index file. I tried to remove it with `rm -f .git/index` and reset it with `git reset`, but I always get error messages like `fatal: index file open failed: input/output error`. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Looks like a file system error

Comment: Have you tried restarting your system? Sounds dumb but maybe a file descriptor can't be freed (or something like that...).

Comment: @Max Leske: Yes, I restarted the system. The problem remains...

Comment: Then I'd run a filesystem check.